# HystrixRunTimeException: <operation> timed-out and fallback failed

Tags: java, hystrix

I'm using hystrix 1.3.7 and my hystrix command has a fallback method defined as well. So it is setup as follows:

```
public final Optional<ImageData> run() throws Exception {
 // does api call to get resized image from a service
}

@Override
public final Optional<ImageData> getFallback() {
    // falls back to processing the image locally.
}
```

However, I have realized that some times (not all times) when the timeout occurs for Hystrix, it seems like it does not execute the logic in getFallback method and throws HsytrixRuntimeException. Here is the stacktrace:

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: imageResize timed-out and fallback failed.
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:980)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:59)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:595)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:587)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1121)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1138)
at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could this be because hystrix is not configured properly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting your code in `getFallback` in try/catch and log the exceptions thrown. From the log I'd say something there throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs I understand that your run() method got failed and the fall back is invoked. The logic you have inside the fallback also seems to get failed. Recommendation is that, fallback should be coded in such a way that it never gets failed. Please check your fallback code if that is failing. Either handle the failure inside fallback or simply move the logic somewhere out of fallback.